# Ubuntu Core viewing all IoT onboarded devices

Tags: ubuntu-one, ubuntu-core

I installed Ubuntu Core 20 and Ubuntu Core 22 on two separate devices on my network. I can SSH into these devices easily.

Before this I setup a Ubuntu One account and uploaded an SSH key.  From reading and watching videos about Ubuntu Core I should be able to manage these devices.  I should be able to see them and deploy packages to them.

I was imaging a dashboard like BalenaCloud or AWS Greengrass where I can see these these devices.

Is there a dashboard somewhere within Ubuntu One account when I can see these devices?

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what videos you have watched? It's hard for us to guess what information you have come across.

Comment: I was watching the following videos:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLRdQ8T-7qY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NY39v0oubyI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NDWqH1SrGs

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe remote device management is part of the default Ubuntu One account panel. Maybe what you have seen in video are demonstrations of  [Canonical Landscape](https://ubuntu.com/landscape) (which is a business solution provided by Canonical).

Gathering from [this article](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/connect-with-ssh), it's my understanding that an Ubuntu Core device is tied to your Ubuntu One account. This simply means that any **public SSH key** uploaded in the [Ubuntu One account](https://login.ubuntu.com/ssh-keys) will automatically sync to the Ubuntu One device.

To actually log in to the device, you need to do so by conventional means. So this will be any SSH application on a device that can reach your Ubuntu One device. Devices on an internal network can reach each other, but to reach devices from the Internet, you still need to set up DNS and possibly port forwarding to reach your devices.

*If you need a business solution for managing Ubuntu Core devices (like Landscape), this is a [commercial service](https://ubuntu.com/internet-of-things/management) provided by Canonical, and not supported here.*

Comment: thank you so much for explaining this.  The images that show example of device management look great.  

I am glad that it is offered as a professional service.  

Can you also tell me what the difference is between Canonical Landscape and the "IoT Management" project https://github.com/canonical/iot-management ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that .. 